# PlayerPrefs not working on android device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try my mobile game on unity , i can see my score where I get from another scene with PlayerPrefs.

But when I try this game on a mobile phone it doesn't show up. I try many things but can't fix it. Is there any solutions for this problem ?

```
SCENE 1

   private float topScore = 0.0f;
     public Text scoreText;
     public Text startText;
 
  scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(topScore).ToString();
```

// I get top score from player position

```
             PlayerPrefs.SetString("CurrentScore", scoreText.text);
```

SCENE 2

```
public Text OverScore;
 void Start()
     {
         OverScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("CurrentScore");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend staying away from player prefs all together and instead saving to a file. Player prefs is very limited in what it can save and has problems with creating garbage files. Saving to a file allows for storage of much more information in a neater fashion as well as being a better practice to follow. Here's a [Brackeys tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido) on how to save and load to a file.

Comment: I try it , it's very usefull tutorial thank you. I solve my problem with this tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Use Save Method after you setting your player prefs and continue using it

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("CurrentScore", scoreText.text);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

[unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)